# sed: update 2 similar variables in a file but keep the upper and lowercase

Tags: bash, sed, variable

I have 2 variables in a file like below that I need to assign a new value inserted by one user input:  `read -p "Enter CName Name : "  CName`

```
sid=C02SBX
SID=C02SBX
```

When I run the following GNU `sed` statement:

```
sed -i "s/sid=.*/sid=$CName/gI" dbca2.rsp
```

it will update the variables as follow:

```
sid=C03SBX
sid=C03SBX
```

Question: How could I make sure that the second `sid` before the `=` sign should always remain upper case e.g. `SID=C03SBX` while the first `sid` stays lowercase. Also both `sid` and `SID` after the `=` sign should always be uppercase e.g (`=C03SBX`) no matter if the user input lower or uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping `\(...\)` and referencing (`\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second etc.):

```
sed -i "s/\(sid=\).*/\1${CName^^}/gI" dbca2.rsp
```

For turning the user input to uppercase, the shell is used: `${var^^}`

Comment: Philippos, I tried you suggestion but the second occurrence of sid= remains in lowercase.

Comment: Impossible. Are you sure you reverted the input file? You already changed it with the `-i` option, so you have to fix it. Of course the script can't revert anything to a prior state.

Comment: Philippos, ok with a little bit of tweak it worked: 
sed -i "s/\(sid=\).*/\1${CName^^}/1I" dbca2.rsp
sed -i "s/\(sid=\).*/\1${CName^^}/2I" dbca2.rsp

.I had to remove the g and add 1 and 2 for first and second occurence.

Comment: But both are on different lines?!

Comment: Yes they are on different lines.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, you should not embed *data* in the *code* arguments of language interpreters whether they're shells, `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, etc.

Doing so invariably introduces command injection vulnerabilities.

So things like <strike>`sed -e "code $data"`</strike>, <strike>`sh -c "code $data"`</strike>, <strike>`eval "code $data"`</strike>, <strike>`perl -e "code $data"`</strike> (note the *double* quotes inside which the `$var`s are expanded to the contents of the shell variable) should be removed from  your vocabulary.

The data should be passed via channels intended for data, not code. `sed` (contrary to `sh`, `awk` and any modern or less modern programming language) doesn't have such channels, so the only option there is to sanitise that data, but then again there have been better alternatives to `sed` since the 80s.

Here, you can use:

```
perl -pi -s -e 's/\bsid=\K.*/\U$value/i' -- -value="$CName" -- "$file"
```

Note how the code argument is fixed: `s/\bsid=\K.*/\U$value/i`, and the data (the contents of the `$CName` shell variable) is passed as a separate non-code argument, one intended to pass values (by assigning to the `$value` perl variable).

Also note:

- `-i` (copied from `perl`) is a non-standard option in `sed`.
- same for the `I` flag to the `sed` command.
- no need for `g` as the `.*` will match to the end of the line so there can only be one substitution per line. It could make sense in `s/\bsid=\K\S*/\U$value/gi` where we match `sid=` followed by any number of non-whitespace characters where it would then change `sid=foo SID=bar` on a single line to `sid=new-value SID=new-value`.
- `perl` (contrary to `sed` which interpret the input as text encoded in the user's locale) by default considers each byte as a character, so it will still work correctly if the file contains bytes not forming valid characters in the user's locale.
- `\U` (from ex/vi) turns what follows to uppercase. Note that by default, it only works for ASCII letters. Also supported by some `sed` implementations but not all and not standard. Alternatively, you could have the shell convert the value to uppercase with `typeset -u CName` in ksh/zsh, or use `$CName:u` in tcsh/zsh or `${(U)CName}` in zsh, or `${CName^^}` in bash. Those would generally interpret the text in the locale's encoding and change the case according to the locale's rules. So for instance, `i` could be changed to `I` or `İ` depending on the locale, and that `İ` could be encoded as a 0xdd byte or the bytes 0xc4 0xb0 depending on whether the locale uses iso8859-9 or UTF-8 as the charmap for instance.
- note the `\b` for *word `b`oundary*, so it doesn't match `sid=foo` in `setsid=foo` for instance. Also supported by some `sed` implementations while some others have `\<`/`\>` (from ex/vi) or `[[:<:]]`/`[[:>:]]` for that instead.
- `\K` specifies the start of what is to be `K`ept in the match. With old versions of `perl`, you'd use `s/(sid=).*/$1\U$value/i`, that is capture the  `sid=` part with parenthesis and recall it in the replacement with `$1`. Or use a look behind operator `s/(?<=sid=).*/\U$value/i` though makes it look a bit too complex IMO.
- as an alternative to `-s` with `-var=value`, you can use environment variables to pass the data: `VALUE=$CName perl -pi -e 's/\bsid=\K.*/\U$ENV{VALUE}/i' -- "$file"`. That would be preferable if the value is sensitive and should not be exposed in the output of `ps -Af`. That's also the approach you'd use in `awk` (`ENVIRON["VALUE"]` there) as the other value passing channels there mangle data containing backslashes.
- to read an arbitrary string from the user, the syntax in `bash` is `IFS= read -rp 'Prompt: ' var` (`IFS= read  -r 'var?Prompt: '` in other Korn-like shells). But prompting the user is generally not the best approach as it makes your script unnecessarily harder to automate or reuse with the same parameters. It's generally better to take input as command line arguments, such as `you-script thenewCN` where the argument is available in `$1` or do proper standard command line parsing with the standard `getopts` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the lines to replace case-insensitively, but only modify the part beginning with `=`, rather than the whole line:

```bash
 sed -e "/^[Ss][Ii][Dd]=/s/=*/=${^^CName}/"
```

Note that `${^^…}` to upcase a parameter is [a Bash feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), not a standard POSIX shell construct.